# Problemas con position dentro de la función geom_errorbar (ggplot)

Tags: r

Estoy intentando hacer un gráfico de medias de una variable denominada "Ronda" con intervalos de confidencia al 95%. Dado que las medias de Ronda son similares, deseo separar los puntos de las medias y las barras de error para que no aparezcan superpuestos.

Sin embargo, estoy teniendo dificultades para separar las líneas de error. Parece como si el código no leyese `position_dodge(0.3)` dentro de `geom_errorbar`.

Aquí el código que uso:

```
y <- datos$Ronda
z <- datos$Condicion
g <- datos$Terapia
g = factor(g, levels = c(0,0.1))
z = factor(z, levels = c("High isolation", "Moderate isolation", "Low isolation"))
data <- data.frame(y,z,g)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales) 
data %>%
  group_by(g, z) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),                             #Estimación de la media
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             #Error estandar de la estimación de la media. 
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      #Techo del intervalo. 
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%  #Piso del intervalo al 95%.
  #mutate(clave = paste("z",z,"x", x, sep="")) %>%       #Genero una clave única para cada combinación de x y z. 
  ggplot(aes(x = g, y = media, color = z)) +
  geom_point() + 
  #Para que genere una salida gráfica cuando sólo hay un data point.
  geom_point(aes(group = z), size=2, position=position_dodge(0.3)) +                       #Las líneas que unen los puntos de cada grupos xz
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup,            #Intervalor al 95% para cada punto. 
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.1,colour="black",position=position_dodge(0.3)) + 
  #theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Terapia", y = "Ronda", color = "Condicion") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("1", "2","3"), values = c("red", "green","blue")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))
```

Aquí el gráfico que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí un link a los [datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9bo7xpsgrpab9z/datos_1.csv?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione tendrías que agregar el argumento `group = z` en el  `aes()` de `geom_errorbar`.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
data %>%
  group_by(g, z) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),                             
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%
  # Gráfico
  ggplot(aes(x = g, y = media, color = z, group = z)) +   # group = z para que funciones position_dodge() Y salgan las barras de error en negro
  geom_point(aes(group = z), 
             size=2, 
             position = position_dodge(0.3)) +                       
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup,            
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),                      
                width=0.1,
                colour="black",                       # Si eliminas esta línea no es necesario group = z, color funcionaría con position_dodge()
                position=position_dodge(0.3)) + 
  # Etiquetas
  labs(x = "Terapia", 
       y = "Ronda", 
       color = "Condicion") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("1", "2","3"), values = c("red", "green","blue")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))
```

## ¿Por qué?

Porque el `position_dodge` de `geom_point` responde al argumento `color` que definiste en el primer `aes()` de tu función. Lo que hace es mover horizontalmente el elemento geométrico por cada grupo de `z`. Sin embargo en `geom_errorbar` estás definiendo un color constante con `colour = "black"` fuera de `aes`. Por eso `position_dodge()` no tiene efecto, no tiene grupos definidos sobre los que trabajar. Al definir un `group =` haces algo similar a lo que obtienes con`color` (definir grupos), pero estos ya no dependen del color.

Alternativamente podrías quitar el `colour = "black"` en `geom_errorbar()` y en ese caso tendrías cada barra de error del mismo color del punto y no sería necesario pasar el argumento `group = z`.
Depende de tu gusto, personalmente prefiero las barras de error en negro.

## Resultado usando `group = z`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Sin embargo, los puntos originales de las medias permanecen alineados en el medio. ¿Existe alguna forma de eliminarlos para evitar confusión?

Comment: Ya está, `geom_point()` estaba duplicado, pensé que lo necesitabas y lo no modifiqué.